# c++ run functions from console

Tags: c++, console

I need to make following feature to my c++ programm:

When i run it, i type name of someone function, which i described in my program, and this function run. How to make it automatic? Not like my current code:

```
func1(){...}
func2(){...}
....
func50(){...}
int main(){
    string function; 
    cin>>function;
    if (function == "func1") funk1();
    if (function == "func2") func2();
    if (function == "func3") funk3();
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

because i have many functions. Which instruments i could use?

Comment: what's the difference between the functions. are they completely arbitrary. who define them. why are you using c++ for this. is it a homework assignment

Comment: You could perform a symbol lookup on the user-input string, but this varies from platform to platform, I'm not sure how to achieve it on some platforms, and I'm also not sure if you can do a symbol search within the executable code you're running, or if it only works with library imports...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, functions are absolutely different. I described all functions, i use it to convert some information to diffirent formats. It's homework, and it's nesessary to use c++ for it.

Comment: std::map with the key a std::string and the value a function pointer is good and easy for me. Thanks to @Luchian Grigore

Answer (score 4):

You can't make it completely automatic because C++ doesn't have reflection.

Any other automation you can cook up will basically be very similar to what you already have.

Some other options would be:

- having a `std::map` with the key a `std::string` and the value a function pointer.
- multiple classes with the function inside them and an abstract factory that gives you a correct instance based on the `std::string`.

Comment: But C/C++ has the preprocessor! This allows to define a function and put it into a map at the same time (see my answer below).

Comment: @coproc there will always be ways to abuse the language, but they remain just that - abuses. Besides, you seem to think that using a preprocessor makes it somehow automatic. It doesn't. You just have less to type. And in the meantime, you introduced a new class whose sole responsibility is adding objects to the map.

Comment: Can you show me a commonly accepted definition of "abuse of the language"? It is not only typing less, it also avoids repeating yourself (see the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) When you want to e.g. change the name of a function, you want to do that in only one place. And what is wrong with a simple helper class that saves you from manually registering 50 functions?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion simplest way is to use `std::map<std::string, std::function<...> >` and then create a global map from your functions and lookup on map:

```
typedef std::function<void()> my_function;
typedef std::map<std::string, my_function> functions_map;

void test1() {...}
void test2() {...}
void test3() {...}

#ifndef _countof
#    define _countof(array)    ( sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) )

std::pair<std::string, my_function> pFunctions[] = {
    std::make_pair( "test1", my_function(&test1) ),
    std::make_pair( "test2", my_function(&test2) ),
    std::make_pair( "test3", my_function(&test3) )
};
functions_map mapFunctions( pFunctions, pFunctions + _countof(pFunctions) );

void main() {
    std::string fn;
    while( std::cin >> fn ) {
        auto i = mapFunctions.find( fn );
        if( i != mapFunctions.end() )
            i->second();
        else
            std::cout << "Invalid function name" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't give full code to homework questions! - showing the right direction does more good than full code.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Sorry I didn't think it is for homework, but you are absolutely right! So much thanks for the note

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, dont worry. The main part of homework is writing converters for many formats, but you're right. I needed only right direction, thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other solutions one can use a map from function name to function pointer to get the function pointer. By the use of a macro one can come very close to what you intend (no need to manually fill the map). Finally your code will look similar to this:

```
DECLARE_FUNC(f1)
{
    std::cout << "calling f1" << std::endl;
}

DECLARE_FUNC(f2)
{
    std::cout << "calling f2" << std::endl;
}

// ... more functions

int main()
{
    std::string function; 
    std::cin >> function;
    TFunc f = s_funcs[function]; // get function pointer for name
    if (f)
        f();
    // ...
```

To be able to do this you need the following definitions:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// the common type of all functions
typedef void (*TFunc)(void);

// a static map of name -> function
static std::map<std::string, TFunc> s_funcs;

// this class we need to statically add functions to the map
class FuncAdder
{
public:
    FuncAdder(std::string name, TFunc f)
    {
        s_funcs[name] = f;
    }
};

// finally the macro for declaring + adding + defining your function
#define DECLARE_FUNC(f) void f(); FuncAdder f##Adder(#f,f); void f()
```

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion. You're implying introducing a macro makes the whole thing automatic, but it doesn't. You just have less to type. In the end it's just an abuse of the language.

Comment: @Luchian What do you mean by "it doesn't" (make the registration automatic)? Of course, this is an automatic registration of the functions in the map. Are you aware that also the boost library uses an analogous technique to e.g. register test functions in its unit testing library? (see the macro BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE)

Comment: I'm not in the mood for a debate. I take it you don't know the pitfalls of using macros - so therefore there's no point to it.